# Need to move mov file to a folder - Applescripts

Tags: applescript

I tried to find an easy way to **move** a file using applescripts for folders with spaces.

The problem is that I want to move one file into another folder.

Folder origin"/Users/xxx/Desktop/PC 1"
Folder destination "/Users/xxx/Desktop/PC 1/xxx/video folder"

The file to move is a .mov file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution:

```
do shell script ("startPath=\"$HOME/Desktop\"
fileName=\"video file.mov\"
destPath=\"$startPath/video folder.pkg/MOVIE DATA folder\"
cp \"$startPath/$fileName\" \"$destPath\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Finder should not have problems with spaces in paths.

```
tell application "Finder"

 # Specifying Applescript path to an existing object:
 # alias "path:to:folder:file.mov"
 set destFolder to alias (((path to desktop) as text) & "PC 1:video folder")
 set movFile to alias (((path to desktop) as text) & "PC 1:test.mov")

 move movFile to destFolder
end tell
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your message, that script open a window to pick the file. 
But what I would like to do is to move an specific file, no need to choose it, how can that be done? 
Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but what happen if the folder have a dot as part of the name? Example:

Users/Users/Desktop/package.pkg/movie where package.pkg is a folder name.

Comment: There is no problem with dots in Mac OS paths. The only character that not works is the colon because it's the separator. The use of slash or space is not recommended too.

Comment: This is the error I get in applescripts console:
error "Finder got an error: Can’t make document file \"video folder.STpkg\" of folder \"Desktop\" of folder \"walter\" of folder \"Users\" of startup disk into type folder." number -1700 from document file "video folder.STpkg" of folder "Desktop" of folder "walter" of folder "Users" of startup disk to folder

Comment: I am using OS Mavericks by the way